# Is there an injective map from $C[0, 1]$ to $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Is there an injective map from $C[0, 1]$ to $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$? Where $C[0, 1]$ denote the set of continuous real valued functions on $[0, 1]$, and $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ be the set of all sequences of real numbers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: Both have the cardinality of continuum, so the answer is yes.

Answer (score 7):

Arrange the rationals in $[0,1]$ in  sequence $(r_1,r_2,...)$. The map $f \to (f(r_1),f(r_2)...)$ is an injection from $C[0,1]$ to  $\mathbb R^{N}$. This is because if two continuous functions coincide on the set of rational numbers then they coincide everywhere.

[If $f(r_n)=g(r_n)$ for all $n$ then $f(x)=g(x)$ for all rationals $x$. For any $x \in [0,1]$ there exists a sequence of rational numbers $x_i$ converging to $x$. Hence $f(x)=\lim f(x_i)=\lim g(x_i)=g(x)$. Thus $f =g$].

Comment: Sir, please add more information, I can't understand.

Comment: @Rishav If two functions agree on a dense set then they are the same. He added the proof too.